# Case expression "missing keyword" error

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following table:

```
City     | Inhabitants | Magnitude
---------+-------------+--------
Zuerich  |  100000     | city
London   | 5000000     | city
New York | 5000000     | city
```

I want a read out a select query that if there are 5000000 inhabitants it has to give out "big city" like this:

```
City     | Inhabitants | Magnitude
---------+-------------+---------
Zuerich  |  100000     | city
London   | 5000000     | bigcity
New York | 5000000     | bigcity
```

I've tried it with this case statement but it didn't work

```
SELECT
    CASE magnitude
       WHEN inhabitants LIKE '%5000000%'
          THEN 'bigcity'
       ELSE NULL
    END AS magnitude
```

I always get a "missing keyword" error.

How can I write this query correctly?

Comment: Remove the word `magnitude` after `Case`.

Comment: In addition to what Siyual wrote: `LIKE` is for character values, not for numbers. You probably want `when inhabitants > 5000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `LIKE` ? is it a number? can it be 050000000? or 500000005? if not the `LIKE` is unnecessary and normal comparison should be used.

Also, `ELSE null` is not correct, since it seems you want the alternative to be `city`

```
SELECT t.city,
       t.inhabitants,
       CASE WHEN t.inhabitants = '5000000' THEN 'bigcity'
                                           ELSE t.magnitude
       END as magnitude
FROM YourTable t
```

If my assumptions are wrong, replace my comparison with the `LIKE` like you used it.

Comment: Do not add code only. explain what you have done and why

Comment: it could be 05550000 or even a word

Comment: No , I mean, if its `05000000` , should it be `bigcity` or `city` ? @nic

Comment: the example is a bit wrong, i need to use a "like" statement because i also need it to do the same comparison with words

Comment: Well, my code works either way, take the template and change it as you pleased.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` syntax is bit wrong. It should be

```
case when <condition> then <value> else <default> end
```

So for your case it should be

```
select case 
 when inhabitants like '%5000000%' then 'bigcity'
else 'City' end as Magnitude
```

Comment: if i do this, everything that isn't 'bigcity' will display as null